# insert data to parent and child table at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have here three tables

```
 customer table
-----------------------------
|customer_id | customer_Name |
-----------------------------
product table
-----------------------------
| product_id | event_Name    |
-----------------------------
reservation table
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|reserve_id | customer_id | product_id | date_usage | motif | venue |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is I want to insert data to reservation table at the same time with the parent tables. how will I do this using PHP ? I’ve searched the web and I’ve red about using stored procedures but I don't know how to use procedures.
how will I code this using php? thanks in advance.

PHP CODE:

```
$price2 = $_POST['price1'];
$pack2 = $_POST['pack1'];
$name = $_POST['textinput11'];
$motif = $_POST['textinput22'];
$venue = $_POST['textinput44'];
$event2 = $_POST['events1'];
$currentdate = date('Y/m/d');


$reserve = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation_info(Event_Motif,Event_Venue,Date_Subtmitted,Date_of_Usage) VALUES('$motif','$venue','$currentdate','$date2')");
$customer = mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer(CustomerName) VALUES('$name')");
$product  = mysql_query("INSERT INTO product_t(Event_Type,Price) VALUES('$event2','$price2')");


if($customer & $product & reserve){
    echo "You have successfully reserved";
}
```

Comment: Your question is far from clear, please tell us what is that you are trying to achieve. From what I get, you have a given customer that reserves a product. Why do you insist on doing it at the same time ? Why cant you just take the customer and the product id the moment the user decides to reserve and insert a record in the reservations ?

Comment: you should just kick off two inserts one for customers and one for reservations.. assuming its a new customer.

Comment: @AngelIliikov whenever i submit the data from my web page to my database it just saves the data in the parent tables but not in the child because of foreign relationship. how will insert data to my parent table at the same time to the child table?

Comment: @Shadow how will i code that using transactions?

Comment: @drandrebandal it does not really matter if you use transactions or not, the key is to insert records into the parent tables first, then into the child tables. Post your php code where you try to insert a reservation for a new customer.

Comment: @Shadow i've updated the php code.

Comment: oh boy, this code is insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the order of the insert statements. First, you try to insert a row into the reservations table, which is the child table, but you do not have a cudtomer_id yet.

Setting transactions aside, insert first into the customers table to create your customer. Based on your code I belive customer_id is an auto increment field. So, after inserting into the customer table call [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function to retrieve the newly created customer id.

Then repeat the same with the products table.

Finally, execute the insert into the reservations table, but this time use the 2 ids you retrieved to explicitky provide customer and product ids in the query.

Note1: do not use mysql extension, it is deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Note2: you can encapsulate the above inserts into a transaction. In a production code I would encourage you to do so, if it's only for learning, then no need to bother just yet.

Comment: unfortunately i don't know what is the syntax of pdo BUT when i appplied your steps  IT WORKS using php. THANKS FOR YOUR TIME SIR.

Comment: Mysqli would be a more straightforward choice than PDO.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use transactions. Algorithm looks like:

1. BEGIN;
2. Insert rows into parent tables
3. Insert reservation
4. COMMIT;

Transactions guarantee your commands will run simultaneously (in a simple language, skipping technical details)

Comment: How would you insert a reservation without knwoing who made a reservation? It's the other way around: first you insert the data in the parent tables and then into the child tables.